# PHP wont send sql data from to database when submitting?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am new to PHP and I am making a insert function which will insert the html input into my Sql database but at the moment when I submit nothing happens and no information is entered into the database. Any help on how I can get the in-putted information to submit to the database would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

  <div align = "center">


           <form method = "POST" class="basic-grey">
           <h1><i>Insert</i></h1>
              <label>Title  :<input type = "text" name="title"/></label>
              <label>Content  :<input type = "text" name="content"/></label>
              <label>User  :<input type = "text" name="user"/></label>

              <label><input type = "submit" value = "submit"/></label>
           </form> 

           <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error ?></div>

           </div>
</html>
<?php

include_once 'db_config.php';

session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login_user']) && $_SESSION['login_user'] != '')) {

header ("Location: login2.php");

 }


if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {



$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$user = $_POST['user'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'diary' ('ID', 'TITLE', 'CONTENT', 'USER') 
VALUES (NULL, '$title','$content', '$user',)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
header("location: results.php");
 } else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
$conn->close();


?>
```

Comment: Database connection is completed successfully?

Comment: Try print_r($conn->query($sql)); to see what the problem is

Comment: Won't work because you don't have anything named 'submit' for `if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {` to test.

Comment: Also, I would suggest that you fix the sql injection you have there ;) .. (what happens if the user adds " ') " as a postvalue?

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have changed the sql query so it is correct and named the submit button but still no result. Sorry for my lack of knowledge on the topic.

Comment: Are you getting any errors now?

Comment: EDIT i have fixed it now and now the results are showing. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script doesn't won't work because you don't have anything named 'submit' for `if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {` to test. Fix that by naming your submit button:

```
<label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></label>
```

Once clicked now the button's name will appear in the `$_POST` array.

---

In addition: `session_start()` should be right after your opening PHP tag.

[Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Your error checking will reveal that you have quoted instead of back ticked table and column names and that you have an extra comma. Change your insert query as follows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `diary` (`ID`, `TITLE`, `CONTENT`, `USER`) VALUES (NULL, '$title','$content', '$user')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using invalid mysql syntax. You are using wrong string literal ' for table name and columns name. You can use this ` , or no literal at all.

Option 1 :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `diary` (`ID`, `TITLE`, `CONTENT`, `USER`) VALUES (NULL, '$title','$content', '$user')";
```

Option 2 :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO diary (ID, TITLE, CONTENT, USER) VALUES (NULL, '$title','$content', '$user')";
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you didn't use name of 'submit' for executed like :

```
<input type="submit" **name="simpan"** value="SIMPAN"/>
```